# opencv detectMultiScale haarcascade_eye takes a couple of seconds on first image

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

```
eyes_cascade.detectMultiScale(cropedImg, eyes_, 1.2, 3);
```

While running a cropped image of the face on detectMultiScale to detect the eyes will take at least 1-2 seconds for the first image and ~30 ms each for the next incoming images.
The size of the cropped image will always differ, a likely case would be 352x528.

What is the reason for that delay, and is there a work around to initlize it at the start to overcome the initial delay?

Using OpenCV `3.4.5`.

Comment: can be better sharing the rest of the code

Comment: Could be related of the loading time of the shared libraries the first time they are called? Something happens for these kind of libs

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question

`detectMultiScale(cropedImg, eyes_, 1.2, 2, 0 | cv::CASCADE_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT | cv::CASCADE_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH | cv::CASCADE_DO_CANNY_PRUNING | cv::CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE);`

passing in the flags reduced the lag and increased the performance of the application.